# C++/WinRT ApplicationDataContainer without a package identity

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, c++-winrt

I'm experimenting with a Windows Console Application (C++/WinRT) and so far successfully made use out of the the Storage API and a few others with no issues. Now i'd like to try and use the ApplicationDataContainer class instead of making use of Winreg.h.

I've followed the C++ code example from here and tried my own things:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.applicationdatacontainer?view=winrt-19041

It seems that creating a settings object relies on a package identity which I don't want to use.

```
ApplicationDataContainer localSettings{ ApplicationData::Current().RoamingSettings() }; // Error
// winrt::hresult 0x80073d54 : The process has no package identity.
```

I understand that ApplicationData::Current() relies on using an identity. But it seems like the only way to make use of ApplicationDataContainer is to initialize in these two ways:

```
ApplicationDataContainer localSettings{ ApplicationData::Current().LocalSettings() };
// Or
ApplicationDataContainer localSettings{ ApplicationData::Current().RoamingSettings() };
```

Is there any way make use of the ApplicationDataContainer API without a package identity, or perhaps another way to initialize this class?

This is also a learning experience so it doesn't matter if the solution only gives partial use of the api. Easy access to local/roaming folders isn't necessary either. I'm happy to store the settings file in a custom location.

Comment: Currently, we can only create a ApplicationDataContainer  instance by using ApplicationData::Current() and as you said, the ApplicationData::Current() method needs a package identity. So we can not use ApplicationDataContainer  directly in desktop app.

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT thanks for the info. Is there plans to support this in a desktop app in the future?

Comment: The ApplicationData::Current() provides access to the app data store associated with the app's app package, the console app can not create an app package and you could use the [Windows Application Packaging Project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-packaging-dot-net) to wrap your app to generate a package.

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT Thanks for that. Do you know if the reliance on package manifests will be reduced in the future?  
I am perfectly happy with creating a win32 app, #include <windows.h> and using any of the winapi's I want freely. I know exactly what goes into the compiled exe. But I don't know how I feel about these extra steps involved in Win10 programming..
EG: 
I have no care for the windows store and don't want to add support to my programs for it. 
I don't fully understand what the package manifests do to my programs, like does MS add telematry calls to my app?

Comment: I don't want to add arbritary restrictions to my app. If I want to use a specific API of X reasons i'd just simply like to go ahead do it instead of tweaking a manifest file often.  etc.

Comment: The [package manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/appx-package-manifest) is an XML document that contains the info the system needs to deploy, display, or update a Windows app, etc. In addition, about if the reliance on package manifests will be reduced in the future, 
 you could continue to follow official documents and the release news.